# How to connec to Remote server in SPSS Modeler

Tags: oracle, spss

I'm trying to connec to a remote data base server and all i can found in "Tools"-> "Database" is "Local Server".
Which by the way is working.
I need to be able to connect to a remote oracle server, is it possible? 
I search in the documentation here: [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/dbconnectionsdialog.htm)
 and all i can fount is explanation on local connection.
In the photo we can see only local server option.

Thank you.
[image: Only local server]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install the proper and supported ODBC driver for the database system that you are connecting to. Please refer to [Database Access](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.1.1/modeler_install_authuserlic_enduser_ddita/common/installation/common_install_clem_dbaccess.html) from the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few resources that about IBM's SPSS Modeler connections with remote/local servers.

[Failed to connect to server Local Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21487653)

And

[Connecting to IBM SPSS Modeler Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_18.1.1/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/entities/serverlogindialog.html)

IBM provides you all the resources that will let you perform all the operations using SPSS, and hope you find the solution with these docs. Cheers.